# Adding custom javascript to functions.php in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, templates

I am trying to add a javascript file to my WordPress site, but the file is failing to load. Here is the code from my functions.php file.

```
function add_custom_script() {

wp_register_script('custom_scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'custom.js', array(),'', true);

wp_enqueue_script('custom_scripts');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script' );
```

Thank you

Comment: Add a `/` on `'custom.js'` because `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the template URL without trailing slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use just `wp_enqueue_script()` and as Mithc said `get_template_directory_uri()` doesn't add the trailing slashes.

Try using:

```
function add_custom_script() {

    wp_enqueue_script('custom_scripts', get_template_directory_uri().'/custom.js', array(),'', true);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_script' );
```